# i want to extract table data in a html file using perl

Tags: perl, parsing

I'm a novice programmer. I have around 100 html files and from each file I have to extract data from different rows  and store separately. I wrote the following code, some one please help me figure out the flaws.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TableExtract ;
my$te = HTML::TableExtract->new(headers => [qw('Compound' 'Name' 'Adduct' 'Adduct MW (Da)' 'Compound MW (Da)' 'Delta')]) ;
my @files = </home/akhila/sta/hmdb_hits/com_pks_stn/*.html>;
foreach my $files(@files){
  $te ->parse_file($files) or die "cannot parse file";
  foreach  my $ts ($te->table()){
    print "Table(", join(',', $ts->coords),"):\n";
    foreach  my$row($ts->rows()){
      print join(',', @$row), "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: sorry there was a copying mistake.

Comment: offtopic: Only wondering on what OS starting the interpreter name with uppercase 'P' (/usr/bin/Perl)

Answer (score 1):

You need read about how the [quota like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) works in perl. Try the next code and you will immediatelly see the problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use HTML::TableExtract;

my $te1 = HTML::TableExtract->new(headers => [qw('Compound' 'Name' 'Adduct' 'Adduct MW (Da)' 'Compound MW (Da)' 'Delta')]) ;
print Dumper $te1->{headers};

my $te2 = HTML::TableExtract->new(headers => ['Compound', 'Name', 'Adduct', 'Adduct MW (Da)', 'Compound MW (Da)', 'Delta']) ;
print Dumper $te2->{headers};
```